# Delete from two tables with join?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as follows

```
tbl1              tbl2
id                article_id
title,            image
whole_news
tags,
author,
older (datetime)
```

where tbl1.id -> tbl2.article_id

How to delete records from both tables where older is < 2008-02-10 00:00:00 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402403/mysql-delete-on-join/3402422#3402422).

To summarize, it would look like

```
 delete s, r from tbl1 s left join tbl2 r on s.id = r.article_id where s.older < str_to_date('2008-02-10 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S');
```

But the better solution would be a foreign key constraint with an on delete cascade, if that is an option, then just delete from tbl1 with the appropriate where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)

Comment: Triggers are a poor solution to having properly enforced data relationships at the table level. If data integrity is a concern I would suggest moving to InnoDB before using triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way: You should use FOREIGN KEYS With ON DELETE CASCADE.

Comment: @Distdev: Yes, it does. I forgot to mention. Thank you!