# sql delete id's from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

MySQL version 5.5.37 using phpmyadmin

I have a problem with deleting the ID’s from 2 tables.

The tables are jos_users and jos_vm_user_info

I need to delete the id's from both tables using the ‘registered before‘ date and ‘last visit’ date in jos_users

If I run this -

```
DELETE jos_users,jos_vm_user_info from jos_users,jos_vm_user_info WHERE jos_users. `registerDate` < '2012-12-31 23:59:59' AND `lastvisitDate` < '2012-12-31 23:59:59'
```

I get ‘0 rows deleted’. I would expect over 2000 rows to be deleted

I’ve obviously got something wrong there but I don’t enough about what I’m doing

or is there a better way to do it?

BTW a SELECT using the table and conditional statements works fine

```
SELECT * FROM `jos_users` WHERE  `registerDate` < '2012-12-31 23:59:59' AND `lastvisitDate` < '2012-12-31 23:59:59'
```

It’s getting the id's deleted in the the jos_vm_user_info table that’s the problem.

Comment: asuming these two tables have foreign key relationship, you could use cascade delete to delete the entries in both tables

Comment: Assuming there is a relationship between the tables(?) then I'd set a Foreign Key in the second table and `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Then deleting it from the first table will result in the row also being removed from the table that references it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql delete on join?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402403/mysql-delete-on-join)

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect DELETE syntax..

example of delete syntax:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_name WHERE 1>0;
```

Your delete syntax contain part DELETE **some_column** FROM....

that highlighted part is wrong..

Comment: Actually, I think they might be specifying table names, not columns. You can do multi-table deletes in this way - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html

Look up **Multi-Table Deletes** on that page.

> You can specify multiple tables in a DELETE statement to delete rows from one or more tables depending on the condition in the WHERE clause.

```
DELETE t1, t2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3
WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t2.id=t3.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the answers, much appreciated. It all helps me to understand sql better.
I realised that the best way to achieve the result I want, which is to remove fake users, was to remove all id's that were not in the orders table.
I found the answer here [Delete sql rows where IDs do not have a match from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384127/delete-sql-rows-where-ids-do-not-have-a-match-in-another-table) 
I removed 6000 id's from a total of 10,000 !